# how do i sort an array of dates in date order using php

Tags: php, arrays, date, using

This is the array Iam trying to sort by date.

```
Array ( 
   [0] => 2013 Aug 01 
   [1] => 2013 Aug 02 
   [2] => 2013 Aug 05 
   [3] => 2013 Aug 06 
   [4] => 2013 Aug 07 
   [5] => 2013 Aug 08 
   [6] => 2013 Aug 09
   [7] => 2013 Jul 11
   [8] => 2013 Jul 12
   [9] => 2013 Aug 12 
   [10] => 2013 Aug 13 
   [11] => 2013 Aug 14
   [12] => 2013 Jul 15 
   [13] => 2013 Aug 15 
   [14] => 2013 Jul 16 
   [15] => 2013 Jul 17 
   [16] => 2013 Jul 18 
   [17] => 2013 Jul 19 
   [18] => 2013 Aug 19 
   [19] => 2013 Aug 20 
   [20] => 2013 Jul 22 
   [21] => 2013 Aug 22 
   [22] => 2013 Jul 23
   [23] => 2013 Aug 23
   [24] => 2013 Jul 24 
   [25] => 2013 Jul 25
   [26] => 2013 Jul 26 
   [27] => 2013 Jul 29 
   [28] => 2013 Jul 30 
   [29] => 2013 Aug 30 
)
```

I have tried many methods but it only seems to sort by the day value, the month is ignored.

The values are converted from 01-08-2013 to 2013 Aug 01 using `strtotime()`.
I even tried to remove all strings and just have a integer like 01082013 and still it only look at the day value for it to be sorted.

Thanks in advance.

I tried these methods but only sorts by the day values

[How to sort an array by date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709290/how-to-sort-an-array-by-date)

Link to the code I am using to get this to work http://pastebin.com/Hr0rhUzn

Answer (score 3):

Try like

```
$new_arr = array_map('strtotime',$my_arr);
asort($new_arr);         // For ascending order
foreach($new_arr as $dates) {
     $result_arr[] = date('Y m d' , $dates);
}
print_r($result_arr);
```

Comment: I was thinking about custom sort and also convert string to timestamp. But your method seems to be sorter.

Comment: This is not complete: `date('Y m d');` will always add same date, pass the timestamp to it too

Comment: If you want timestamp then you can directly use it without foreach loop

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ oh thnku for the suggestion...I didnt noticed in flow.Thanku

Comment: And I think its better to send the date in `$my_arr` in the format `01-08-2013`

Answer (score 0):

The strtotime would not return timestamp if date is entered in format "2013 Aug 29" becasue its not a valid input format for strtotime. We need to replace the spaces with dash.
Here is my solution.

```
usort($myDateArray, "dateCompare");
function dateCompare($date1, $date2){
    if($date1 == $date2){
        return 0;
    }
    return (strtotime(str_replace(" ","-",$date1)) < strtotime(str_replace(" ","-",$date2))) ? -1 : 1;
}
```